# most information of htop output disappears

Tags: linux, htop

I got this problem since this morning, `htop` gives following outputs:

[image]

Most information disappears, does anyone know what I did wrong for this?

Thanks!

Edit:

Here are a few things I tried:

1. remove & reinstall `htop`, does not help
2. remove htoprc and restart htop, does not help
3. press "left" many times, does not help
4. check my command line history, I did not find anything unusual

Comment: Does `top` also show high CPU usage and no processes?

Comment: @TimothyMartin Output of `top` is completely normal.

Comment: Were there any updates that immediately preceded this change in behavior?

Comment: @TimothyMartin  I do not remember I did anything unusual.   I also check my command history, it seems normal to me.

Comment: @TimothyMartin I suspect I may type something wrong in `htop` that caused this weird behavior.

Comment: @TimothyMartin I also did "remove & reinstall" `htop`, still does no help.

Comment: What is your OS type/version?  What is the htop version?

Comment: @TimothyMartin My Linux version is 3.19.0-32-generic, distribution release version is Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa, htop version is htop 1.0.2 - (C) 2004-2011 Hisham Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

Some background :
I faced the same issue recently.

[image: same issue]

My work is mostly on my university  high performance cluster and therefore the libraries that I use for computation messes up  my account a lot.

The solution that worked for me was to first check which libraries were loaded with `ldd /usr/bin/htop`. My out was something like this:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffedfd87000)
libncursesw.so.5 => /usr/local/Anaconda/Anaconda3/lib/libncursesw.so.5 (0x00002b84c2bc2000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /usr/local/Anaconda/Anaconda3/lib/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00002b84c2df3000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b84c304f000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/Anaconda/Anaconda3/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002b84c3352000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b84c3564000)
libtinfow.so.5 => /usr/local/Anaconda/Anaconda3/lib/./libtinfow.so.5 (0x00002b84c3931000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000563efed0e000)
```

It might not be very obvious but the dependencies were met through the Anaconda3 libraries, which is pretty awkward. I had asked to load anaconda module in my `~/.bashrc`. This causes a mismatch in the libraries with the ones in the headers.

Solution was to simply unload the anaconda module with `module unload python/Anaconda3`

P.S. This is a very specific solution that worked for me. Can you please write your out from `ldd`?